# SSIS truncate table error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, business-intelligence

Hello I'm new to SSIS and BI.
I'm trying to create a dimension and and the beginning of the work flow i want to truncate my Staging table.
fr some reason this is throwing an error i cant seam to get passed.
any help would be great thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your error description, you are trying to set "Execute SQL" task "Name" property. Please check "Execute SQL" task expressions again. I am able to reproduce same error - check below snapshot.

[image]

[image]

SSIS objects name can't contain these characters - /:[].

New Snapshot after removing special characters from "Name" expression, it works after that -
[image]

[image]

Comment: when i remove the [] it still dosn't execute the task. the code is: "Truncate Table STG_" +   @[System::PackageName]

Comment: It is working for me. Please check my updated answer.